# strcat query (string.h)

Tags: c++, c, strcat

First off :
STRCAT :

[Cplusplus - strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/)

When clearly the definition says :

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Why'd they use char str[80] in the example??? 
Shouldn't they have used a character pointer?

Comment: Think about it; you can pass pointer, but the pointer has to point to *something*, and in this case passing an array provides a pointer to that array since arrays are always passed by reference not by value.

Answer (score 3):

That is because arrays decay into pointers in C/C++. If you define `char s[80]` the value of s will be the address of the first character i.e `&s[0]`

Answer (score 3):

array can also be used as pointer. what `strcat` needs is the pointer to a memory in which it copies the destination string. In this case  `str[80]` will give you the memory that can hold 80 chars.

Answer (score 2):

```
char str[80];
```

declares an array of 80 characters.
However, in C and C++, arrays are implicitly converted to pointers. When you pass an array to a function (such as strcat), it automatically "decays", forming a pointer to the first element of the array.

That's not the same as saying that arrays and pointers are the same thing. They aren't. For example, `sizeof()`  yields different results on the above array, and a `char*`.

Answer (score -1):

An array is, strictly speaking, a pointer to the beginning of a block of memory. So `str` is a `char *` that points to the beginning of 80 characters.

When you index into an array, say position 53, the following is equivalent: `str[53]` is the same as `*(str + 53)` as str is just a `char *` and adding 53 to a character pointer will return a pointer so to get the value inside you have to use an asterisk to dereference the pointer. In effect array notation just makes code more readable in certain circumstances.

Actually a great little trick with arrays of char is when you want to skip over some leading text when copying a string. E.g. let's say your array `str[80]` contains the string `"1023: error in code!"`. And you want to display just the string without the number in front. In this case you could say `printf( "%s", str + 6 )` and only `"error in code!"` would be printed.

Comment: False, and array is not a pointer to the beginning of a block of memory, but rather the block of memory itself. The compiler will provide you with a pointer to the first element implicitly if required, but they are different. Check: `char array[10];char* p=array;assert(sizeof(array)==10); assert(sizeof(p)!=sizeof(array));`

Comment: In your last example, where you write `str+6` the compiler determines that it cannot add a number to an array, so it implicitly converts it to a pointer to the first element and then performs pointer arithmetic to that pointer. At any rate, arrays always decay into pointers at function calls.

Comment: Ah good point dribeas, you're right, an array is not a pointer but can masquerade as one in certain circumstances. Especially with the sizeof operator. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -6):

```
char str[80];
```

Edit:
Opps, I rushed my answer. As dribeas says the statement declares an array and str can be implicitly converted into a pointer when it is used. For instance:

```
++str;
```

is an invalid operation while:

```
char* ptr;
++ptr;
```

isn't.

Comment: False. It declares an array of 80 chars. It is a common misconception that arrays and pointers are the same, they are not. The reason that the code sample works is that an array will be implicitly converted into a pointer to the first element and that will be a `char*`